# Incorrect result for hash calculation

Tags: keccak

According to this link, [https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-155.md][1].

The "signing data" becomes:

0xec098504a817c800825208943535353535353535353535353535353535353535880de0b6b3a764000080018080

The "signing hash" becomes:

0xdaf5a779ae972f972197303d7b574746c7ef83eadac0f2791ad23db92e4c8e53

But I cannot generate this result by https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/keccak_256.html

Which is wrong?

How keccak("0xec098504a817c800825208943535353535353535353535353535353535353535880de0b6b3a764000080018080") make "0xdaf5a779ae972f972197303d7b574746c7ef83eadac0f2791ad23db92e4c8e53"?

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed correct. I just tested this in a different language to remove any ambiguities. Please make sure to use Keccak256 with the original padding, NOT the new SHA3 padding. Remove the '0x' from the hex string, and convert it to bytes.